# Java class, trying to make a method that finds the initial value

Tags: java

I'm just starting to learn classes, and I'm a bit stuck. I'm not sure how I can get this method to find the initial value that was first entered

```
public class DecreasingCounter {
    private int value;

    public DecreasingCounter(int valueAtStart) {
        this.value = valueAtStart;
    }

    public void printValue() {
        // do not touch this!
        System.out.println("value: " + this.value);
    }

    public void decrease() {
        if (this.value > 0) {
            this.value--;
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.value = 0;
    }

    public void setInitial() {
        this.value = 
    }
}
```

it's the last method `setInitial();`that I'm trying to get to work.

Comment: Store the initial value into another field, and reinitialize this.value with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll just need to maintain a reference to the initial value as a member so you can refer back to it later.

```
private final int initialValue;
```

And then modify your constructor like so

```
public DecreasingCounter(int valueAtStart) {
    //store the initial value based on the arg passed in
    this.initialValue = valueAtStart; 

    //go ahead and do whatever we do to reset our counter to the 
    //initial value (avoids duplicating code)
    this.setInitial(); 
}
```

And then finally,

```
public void setInitial() {
    //reset our current value back to the initial value we stored at construction time
    this.value = this.initialValue;
}
```

Comment: Hey, could you explain what you did by adding the line in the constructor? I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: Thank you very much that is really helpful, may I ask why you used 'final' for initialValue?

Comment: @user3261806 Your initial value is set **once** and it is not modified anymore, so you declare it `final`, making it read-only. This also prevents you from _accidentially_ setting it to a different value somewhere else in the code.